# How to Random switch String

Tags: java, user-interface, random

```
error: cannot find symbol
           int n2 = m2*getRandom(10);
                       ^
  symbol: method getRandom(int)

error: cannot find symbol
           int n1 = m1*getRandom(10);
                       ^
  symbol: method getRandom(int)
```

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        l1.setText(t1.getText()+t2.getText());
        if(c1.isSelected())
       {
         l1.setText(t2.getText()+t1.getText());
         if(c2.isSelected())
         {
           int m2 = t2.getText().length();
           int n2 = m2*getRandom(m2);
           String ans2="";
           for(int i2 = t2.getText().length()-1; i2>=0; i2--)
           {
             ans2 += t2.getText().charAt(n2);
           }

           int m1 = t1.getText().length();
           int n1 = m1*getRandom(m1);
           String ans1="";
           for(int i1 = t1.getText().length()-1; i1>=0; i1--)
           {
             ans1 += t1.getText().charAt(n1);
           }
           l1.setText(ans2+ans1);
         }
       }
     }
   }
   );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for the clearly-written question. Okay, so it sounds like you haven't defined a `getRandom` method. Where are you expecting that to come from?

Comment: What should `getRandom(int)` do? And why are you attempting to multiply the result of that with the same value you attempt to pass to the function?